# Load content retrieved via AJAX/MYSQL into jQueryTools overlay

Tags: jquery, ajax, overlay, jquery-tools

New to jQuery and can't get this to work. I've retrieved content from a MYSQL database using jQuery $.ajax(). That part works. You can see that code in the onBeforeLoad event below.

I want this content to load into the jQueryTools overlay. I have dumped that content into a block with the id "contentWrap".

The jQueryTools overlay documentation has an example of loading an external page into an overlay using the onBeforeLoad event, but I have been unable to adapt that code for my purposes. Here is their example, from http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/external.html:

```
onBeforeLoad: function() {

    // grab wrapper element inside content
    var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");

    // load the page specified in the trigger
    wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
}
```

I tried putting my ajax code in a onBeforeLoad event in my overlay call, but didn't work. So how can I load my content directly into the overlay?

Okay, after a few changes, here is the actual running code, which still isn't working:

JQUERY:

```
$("a.noteref[rel]").overlay({
mask: {
    color: '#000',
    loadSpeed: 100,
    opacity: 0.7
},
closeOnClick: true,
fixed: false,
onBeforeLoad: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api.php',
            data: "ID=" + $(this).attr('id').replace('#', ''),
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var id = data[0];
                var vtype = data[1];
                var vcontent = data[2];
                var vlink = data[3];
                var data

                $('#contentWrap').html(vcontent);
                }
        });
        var wrap = this.getOverlay().find("#contentWrap");
        wrap.load();

    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<a hef="http://www.example.com/" class="noteref" id="cite01">Example</a>

<div class="overlay">
    <div id="contentWrap"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can't find `.contentWrap` because you don't have an element with the class of contentWrap. You would need to find it with the id of `#contentWrap` or the class of `.overlay`.

Comment: Can you show the sample running code. may be in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: any solution found for this? a jsfiddle / code example would be very appreciated as well..